# Is it possible to make @dataprovider name generic instead of hardcoding it

Tags: selenium, dataprovider

```
Class1  
  @DataProvider(name = "pdlogin")
        public String[][] pdlogin() {
    
            String data[][]= ExcelUtil.getTresExcelTestData(ExcelSheetNames.Sheet_Name_pdlogin);
            return data;
        }
class2
@Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "pdlogin", dataProviderClass = LoginPage_DataProvider.class)

class3
@Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "pdlogin", dataProviderClass = LoginPage_DataProvider.class)
```

here the name of my @DataProvider is "pdlogin" (which is hardcoded) and i have used this dataprovider name in many @Test methods, now what i want to do is, if i change the name of my dataprovider from "pdlogin" to "pdlogindata" so it must get change everywhere i used it. Currently if i change the dataprovider name so i have to go to each and every class and change it, it is very lengthy process. I aam new into selenium, please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

DataProviders has more precedence.

You can decalage like this  :

```
protected final static String dataProviderName = "pdlogin";
```

and use it like this :

```
 @DataProvider(name = dataProviderName)
 public String[][] pdlogin() {
     String data[][]= ExcelUtil.getTresExcelTestData(ExcelSheetNames.Sheet_Name_pdlogin);
     return data;
 }
```

Remember it has to be `final`.

Now you can keep this in a excel, csv, ini, text file. and can read it.